# Horizontal spacing between 'Chapter' and chapter number in table of content

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, chapters

I am trying to introduce a horizontal spacing between 'Chapter' and chapter no, so the output looks like this: Chapter 1 , not Chapter1

I am copying the whole .tex commands , beacuse I have no idea where to set the spacing command.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{behrooz-thesis}
% Packages
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1in,bottom=1.5in,top=1in,marginparwidth=0.0in,marginparsep=0.0in,headheight=0.0in,headsep=0.0in,footskip=0.5in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{deluxetable}
%\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0.5in plus 1.0pt minus 1.0pt}
%\setlength{\floatsep}{0.25in plus 1.0pt minus 1.0pt}
%\setlength{\intextsep}{0.5in plus 1.0pt minus 1.0pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[font={small}, skip=12pt, format=hang]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
%\DeclareCaptionListFormat{mycaplist}{#2}
%\captionsetup{listformat=mycaplist}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}
%\usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{microtype}
%\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb}
%
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
%setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{3em}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter}
\AtBeginDocument{\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\widthof{\bfseries Chapter }}}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{3pt}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{}
\renewcommand{\cftbeforefigskip}{0.15in}
%\renewcommand\cftpartnumwidth{-2cm}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
%\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0.5in}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage[subrefformat=parens,labelformat=parens]{subfig}
\usepackage{nomencl}

%\usepackage[backend=bibtex,natbib=true,style=authoryear-comp,firstinits=true,uniquename=init]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{ref.bib}
%\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\newcommand {\aj} {Astrophysical Journal}
\newcommand {\aap} {Astronomy and Astrophysics}
\newcommand {\apj} {Astrophysical Journal}
\newcommand {\apjl} {Astrophysical Journal Letters}
\newcommand {\apjs} {Astrophysical Journal Supplement}
\newcommand {\mnras} {Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society}
\newcommand {\nat} {Nature}
\newcommand {\apss} {APSS}
\newcommand{\pasj}{PASJ}
\newcommand{\gca}{Geochimica Cosmochimica Acta}
\newcommand{\pasp}{Publications of the ASP}
\newcommand{\araa}{Annual Review of Astronomy and Astrophysics}
\newcommand{\physrep}{Physics Reports}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Radiative transfer paper %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{deluxetable}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}

\newcommand{\sun}{\odot}
\newcommand{\snia}{SN~Ia}
\newcommand{\sneia}{SNe~Ia}
\newcommand{\dmft}{$\Delta M_{15}(B)$}
\newcommand{\cofs}{$^{56}$Co}
\newcommand{\site}{$^{28}$Si}
\newcommand{\nifs}{$^{56}$Ni}
\newcommand{\mch}{$M_{\rm Ch}$}
\newcommand{\supernu}{\textsc{SuperNu}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[left]{lineno}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{listings,minted}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{font=scriptsize} %change the caption size
\algrenewcommand\alglinenumber[1]{\scriptsize #1:} %change line number size in pseudocode
\algnewcommand{\LineComment}[1]{\Statex \(\triangleright\) #1 \hfill~} %freely positions comments in pseudocode
\algrenewcommand\textproc{}% Used to be \textsc %small alphabets as function name
%\algtext*{EndFor}
%\algtext*{EndIf}
%New definitions
\algnewcommand\algorithmicswitch{\textbf{switch}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmiccase{\textbf{case}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicassert{\texttt{assert}}
\algnewcommand\Assert[1]{\State \algorithmicassert(#1)}%
%New "environments"
\algdef{SE}[SWITCH]{Switch}{EndSwitch}[1]{\algorithmicswitch\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicswitch}%
\algdef{SE}[CASE]{Case}{EndCase}[1]{\algorithmiccase\ #1}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmiccase}%
%\algtext*{EndSwitch}%
\algtext*{EndCase}%
%
%\usepackage[backend=bibtex8,citestyle=numeric-comp,sorting=none,bibstyle=numeric]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{refs.bib}
%\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{urlseen = {accessed},}
%%
%\usepackage{floatrow}
%\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
%\tikzset{>=latex}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,decorations.pathreplacing,positioning}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{external,groupplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9,width=0.9\textwidth,height=0.5\textwidth}
%\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
%\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
%
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
%\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{\bfseries}{}{}{}
%
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}% LoF
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}% LoT
\makeatother
```

Thnaks

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument{\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\widthof{\bfseries Chapter }}}` should actually work, but your preamble is in an incredible messy state, sorry

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the mess too. That suggested line is already included in the .tex file. However, I still don't see the expected outcome, can you just figure out , why?

Comment: I think what you need is to replace `\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter}` with `\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }`. Note here `{Chapter<space>}`